# CPIO command taking too long to complete

Tags: oracle10g, ubuntu-server, vagrant

I'm trying to install Oracle database 10g on an Ubuntu Server 11.04 VM. I am using Vagrant to run it and access it. I downloaded the install package which has a .cpio.gz file extension. Oracle specifies these commands to unpack it:

```
gunzip filename
cpio -idmv filename
```

The gunzip operation worked just fine, but when I run the cpio command it seems to be taking too long. I left it running for over 3 hours and it had not completed. Now, the .cpio file is 764MB. Should it be running this long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the following

```
 cpio -idmvI filename      # note the capital I
```

or

```
 cpio -idmv < filename     # note the 'lower than'
```

otherwise cpio tries to read from *stdin*